# Joomla Admin and Frontend Links not working

Tags: joomla

i am facing a problem after hacking in my `website`. All Links redirecting to `home page`. Any Help ? Shorten URL as `http://goo.gl/28FYH`

In Admin, No `Save`, NO `CLose` `Edit`, nothing is working. ANy help ?

I have tried all the possibilities like to change in `.hataccess`, no help from that.

Comment: With that hacked website, you could infect us :( You don't have a backup ? Did you contact your webhost ? You may receive a backup from them. If no, you may partially rebuild the website, by dumping the DB, creating a fresh new joomla 1.5 installation, install all components, edit the config file to use the "old" DB, and fix the rest of the problems. Don't forget to scan the files against backdoors etc... You may also try to do an "upgrade". Remember backup first !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla 1.5, the links in the backend are managed by JS. Check if all scripts are included properly. You can also open the JS Console of your browser to see what is happening when clicking a link.